# Bootstrap - Table Column Widths Not Sizing Correctly

Tags: javascript, html, css, bootstrap-4

I have a Bootstrap 4 table which shows existing data as well as a row at the bottom to enter another line and submit that. I've setup fixed column widths in the header row but these are not being respected when the table is rendered.

Here's an example:

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="table table-striped table-hover table-bordered">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th style="width:20%">No</th>
      <th style="width:30%">Name</th>
      <th style="width:5%">Phase</th>
      <th style="width:15%">Name</th>
      <th style="width:5%">Day</th>
      <th style="width:5%">Time</th>
      <th style="width:5%">Totals</th>
      <th style="width:10%">Notes</th>
      <th style="width:5%">Action</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>

    <tr id="1956253">
      <td>2368941257</td>
      <td>London Gateway</td>
      <td>23/B</td>
      <td>Planning</td>
      <td>Mon</td>
      <td>7</td>
      <td>7</td>
      <td>lorem ipsum</td>
      <td>N/A</td>
    </tr>



    <tr>
      <td>
        <select name="projectNumber" required>
          <option value=""></option>
          <option value="365541254">365541254</option>
          <option value="874521147">874521147</option>
          <option value="3456467456">3456467456</option>
        </select>
      </td>
      <td id="ProjectName"></td>
      <td id="ProjectPhases"></td>
      <td></td>
      <td>
        <select name="Date" required>
          <option value=""></option>
          <option value="Mon">Mon</option>
          <option value="Tue">Tue</option>
          <option value="Wed">Wed</option>
          <option value="Thu">Thu</option>
          <option value="Fri">Fri</option>
          <option value="Sat">Sat</option>
          <option value="Sun">Sun</option>
        </select>
      </td>
      <td><input type="text" name="Time" required></td>
      <td></td>
      <td><input type="text" name="Notes"></td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td colspan="9">
        <button type="reset" class="btn">Reset</button>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Save</button>
      </td>
    </tr>

  </tbody>
</table>
```

For example the Time column should only be 5% of the width but is taking up much more space. Nothing I've tried has been able to get the specified widths to be respected here.

Comment: Try setting widths for the input. By default, they are that long and that is why it stretches that column.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, you gave width to the `th`s but not the `tr`s - Also, the input field inside the cell is much wider so the entire column gets wider to accommodate.

You could use specific classes for each width to avoid repeating styles.

See demo below

```css
.w-5{
  width: 5%;
}

.w-10
  width: 10%;
}

.w-15{
  width: 15%;
}

.w-20{
  width: 20%;
}

.w-30{
  width: 30%;
}

.w-5 input{
  width:100%;
}

.w-20 select{
  width:100%;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<table class="table table-striped table-hover table-bordered">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th class="w-20">No</th>
      <th class="w-10">Name</th>
      <th class="w-5">Phase</th>
      <th class="w-15">Name</th>
      <th class="w-5">Day</th>
      <th class="w-5">Time</th>
      <th class="w-5">Totals</th>
      <th class="w-10">Notes</th>
      <th class="w-5">Action</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>

    <tr id="1956253">
      <td>2368941257</td>
      <td>London Gateway</td>
      <td>23/B</td>
      <td>Planning</td>
      <td>Mon</td>
      <td>7</td>
      <td>7</td>
      <td>lorem ipsum</td>
      <td>N/A</td>
    </tr>



    <tr>
      <td class="w-20">
        <select name="projectNumber" required>
          <option value=""></option>
          <option value="365541254">365541254</option>
          <option value="874521147">874521147</option>
          <option value="3456467456">3456467456</option>
        </select>
      </td>
      <td id="ProjectName"></td>
      <td id="ProjectPhases"></td>
      <td></td>
      <td>
        <select name="Date" required>
          <option value=""></option>
          <option value="Mon">Mon</option>
          <option value="Tue">Tue</option>
          <option value="Wed">Wed</option>
          <option value="Thu">Thu</option>
          <option value="Fri">Fri</option>
          <option value="Sat">Sat</option>
          <option value="Sun">Sun</option>
        </select>
      </td>
      <td class="w-5"><input class="time" type="text" name="Time" required></td>
      <td></td>
      <td><input type="text" name="Notes"></td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td colspan="9">
        <button type="reset" class="btn">Reset</button>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Save</button>
      </td>
    </tr>

  </tbody>
</table>
```